# Failed to load Pdf Document html-pdf

Tags: node.js, html-pdf

[This](https://plnkr.co/edit/AMJoLFiZQl7ljIZ9MOp7?p=preview) is a  plunker link. I run `pdfSample.js` using node, `pdfsample.html` is actual data to convert into pdf and `generatepdf.html` is used to fetch it .

When i run it, it shows me an error `Failed to load Pdf Document`. I reffered [this sample](https://github.com/bapatel1/node-html-pdf-sample). I am not getting any issue why it is not working?

```
    $http.get(url, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).then(function successCallback(response){
            console.log(response);
            var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
            console.log(file);
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            $scope.loading = false;
            q.resolve(fileURL);

        },
            function errorCallback(response){
                $scope.loading = false;
                q.reject(response);
            });
           /* .success(function (response) {

            })
            .error(function (err) {

            });*/
        return q.promise;
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the blob to the actual data not the response object.

You need `new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'})`

But make sure that when you hit `http://localhost:8081/api/printpdf1` you get the pdf and not an error.

```js
$http.get(url, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).then(function successCallback(response){
            console.log(response);
            var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
            console.log(file);
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            $scope.loading = false;
            q.resolve(fileURL);

        },
            function errorCallback(response){
                $scope.loading = false;
                q.reject(response);
            });
           /* .success(function (response) {

            })
            .error(function (err) {

            });*/
        return q.promise;
    };
```